# I want to display first word from 1st list and display 10 words from 2nd list and so on-python

Tags: python

The code below is for scraping data from webpage.Actually,the output from this code
and output from the another list is to be considered .

```
list2=[]

###-I am collecting all span tags ,storing as text in variable called alpha.

for i in range(len(contents)):
        for j in contents[i].findAll('span'):
            alpha=j.text
#     print(alpha)
            alphachar=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', alpha) #I am eliminating empty lists.
            alphabets=alphachar.split()  #converting to list
            for item in alphabets:
                if item!=[]:
                    list2.append(item)   #I am appending to lists
for (a, b) in zip(li,list2):
            print(a,b)
```

The output of the above code is :

```
AMD AdvancedMicroDevicesInc
BAC BankofAmericaCorp
GE GeneralElectricCo
F FordMotorCo
M MacysInc
PFE PfizerInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
BMY BristolMyersSquibbCo
T ATTInc
JWN NordstromInc
JWN NordstromInc
M MacysInc
LB LBrandsInc
GPS GapInc
SJM JMSmuckerCo
CPRI CapriHoldingsLtd
RL RalphLaurenCorp
BIIB BiogenInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
ADS AllianceDataSystemsCorp
```

Now I have another list called name :

```
name = allbody.findAll('h3')
```

Its output is:

```
Most actives,Gainers
```

Now,I want the output as:

```
 - Most actives

AMD AdvancedMicroDevicesInc
BAC BankofAmericaCorp
GE GeneralElectricCo
F FordMotorCo
M MacysInc
PFE PfizerInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
BMY BristolMyersSquibbCo
T ATTInc
JWN NordstromInc

 - Gainers

JWN NordstromInc
M MacysInc
LB LBrandsInc
GPS GapInc
SJM JMSmuckerCo
CPRI CapriHoldingsLtd
RL RalphLaurenCorp
BIIB BiogenInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
ADS AllianceDataSystemsCorp
```

I tried using nested for loop for names and zip function but didnt work out.Can anyone please help out in this?

Comment: you would need `list2[i:i+10]` to get 10 elements from list. And you have to add 10 to  `i` to get next 10 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is situation when `range(len())` can be useful to generate `i` for `list2[i:i+10]`.

Using

```
for i range(0, len(list2), 10):
```

you can assign to `i` values `0`, `10`, etc. which will create `list2[0:10]`, `list2[10:20]`, etc.

```
list1 = ['Most actives', 'Gainers']

data = '''AMD AdvancedMicroDevicesInc
BAC BankofAmericaCorp
GE GeneralElectricCo
F FordMotorCo
M MacysInc
PFE PfizerInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
BMY BristolMyersSquibbCo
T ATTInc
JWN NordstromInc
JWN NordstromInc
M MacysInc
LB LBrandsInc
GPS GapInc
SJM JMSmuckerCo
CPRI CapriHoldingsLtd
RL RalphLaurenCorp
BIIB BiogenInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
ADS AllianceDataSystemsCorp'''

list2 = data.split('\n')

for name, i in zip(list1, range(0, len(list2), 10)):
    print('\n-', name, '\n')
    for item in list2[i:i+10]:
        print(item)
```

---

**EDIT:** As I know there is no special function for slicing `list2` but you can create own

(source: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks))

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

and then `for`-loop with `zip()` will look nicer

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


list1 = ['Most actives', 'Gainers']

data = '''AMD AdvancedMicroDevicesInc
BAC BankofAmericaCorp
GE GeneralElectricCo
F FordMotorCo
M MacysInc
PFE PfizerInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
BMY BristolMyersSquibbCo
T ATTInc
JWN NordstromInc
JWN NordstromInc
M MacysInc
LB LBrandsInc
GPS GapInc
SJM JMSmuckerCo
CPRI CapriHoldingsLtd
RL RalphLaurenCorp
BIIB BiogenInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
ADS AllianceDataSystemsCorp'''

list2 = data.split('\n')

for name, items in zip(list1, chunks(list2, 10)):
    print('\n-', name, '\n')
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

Comment: I added example with function `chunks()`

Comment: you can keep it as tuples - `list2.append( (a, b) )` - and then you may have to use `for a,b in items: print(a, b)`

Comment: But this prints me only the 

- <h3>Most Actives</h3> 

SBAC
SBACommunicationsCorp

Comment: I don't know what you really have in lists and how you use them - ie. in your question wasn't `<h3>`. Maybe create new question on new page and describe problem with all details. And put full code so we could run it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004270/i-want-to-display-first-word-from-1st-list-and-display-10-words-from-2nd-list-an--I have posted the entire ques.Can you please let me know if tis could be solved?

Comment: it seems you used `data.append( (a,b) )` after `for`-loop but you should use it inside `for`-loop - in place of `print(a,b)`