# I want to display first word from 1st list and display 10 words from 2nd list and so on-python.I tried it using range and zip.it didnt work still

Tags: python

Here,I am creating a list called li which has  tag text and list called list2 that has span text.I am appending it using zip  .Now,I have a third list called name which has 2 values (Most Actives,Gainers).I want Mostactives and then first 10 values from a list,then the gainers and next 10 values.The sample output is shown below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url = 'https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

allbody = soup.find('div',class_='cnnBody_Left wsodContent') 
name = allbody.findAll('h3')   #I am finding the header tags text
```

My output for this would be:

```
Most Actives,Gainers
```

Here,In below I am scraping all the  tags text and storing in a list called li

```
contents=allbody.findAll('table',class_='wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt')
li=[]
for j in range(len(contents)):
        for i in contents[j].findAll('a'):
                title=i.text
                title=title.split()
                for j in title:
                    li.append(j)  #I am scraping all text of   <a> tags and storing it in list
```

My output for this alone would be:

```
['AMD', 'BAC', 'GE', 'F', 'M', 'PFE', 'FCX', 'BMY', 'T', 'JWN', 'JWN', 'M', 'LB', 'GPS', 'SJM', 'CPRI', 'RL', 'BIIB', 'FCX', 'ADS', 'INTU', 'HES', 'STZ', 'COTY', 'TTWO', 'ABMD', 'SNPS', 'TSN', 'CCI', 'SBAC']
```

Now,I am scraping all span tags and storing it in a list and am appending li and list2.

```
list2=[]
for i in range(len(contents)):
        for j in contents[i].findAll('span'):
            alpha=j.text
            alphachar=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', alpha)
            alphabets=alphachar.split()
            for item in alphabets:
                if item!=[]:
                    list2.append(item)


for (a, b) in zip(li,list2):
    print(a,b)
```

My output for this would be:

```
AMD AdvancedMicroDevicesInc
BAC BankofAmericaCorp
GE GeneralElectricCo
F FordMotorCo
M MacysInc
PFE PfizerInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
BMY BristolMyersSquibbCo
T ATTInc
JWN NordstromInc
JWN NordstromInc
M MacysInc
LB LBrandsInc
GPS GapInc
SJM JMSmuckerCo
CPRI CapriHoldingsLtd
RL RalphLaurenCorp
BIIB BiogenInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
ADS AllianceDataSystemsCorp
```

From here,I want the output to be:

```
 - Most actives

AMD AdvancedMicroDevicesInc
BAC BankofAmericaCorp
GE GeneralElectricCo
F FordMotorCo
M MacysInc
PFE PfizerInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
BMY BristolMyersSquibbCo
T ATTInc
JWN NordstromInc

 - Gainers

JWN NordstromInc
M MacysInc
LB LBrandsInc
GPS GapInc
SJM JMSmuckerCo
CPRI CapriHoldingsLtd
RL RalphLaurenCorp
BIIB BiogenInc
FCX FreeportMcMoRanInc
ADS AllianceDataSystemsCorp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed code to group elements when I scrape them so later I don't have to split for 10 elements.

`findAll('table',...)` gives three elements (three tables on page) and for table I create separated `data` to keep values only for this table - so I group data and later I don't have to split them.

To do it I also search rows in tables and in every row I search symbol and full name so I can put them together in `data`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

allbody = soup.find('div', class_='cnnBody_Left wsodContent') 
names = allbody.find_all('h3')   #I am finding the header tags text
names = [x.text for x in names]
#print(names)

contents = allbody.find_all('table', class_='wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt')

tables = [] # keep three tables

for item in contents:
    data = [] # list for single table

    for tr in item.find_all('tr')[1:]: # find rows in table - skip row with headers `[1:]`
        a = tr.find('a')  # get only from first column
        a = a.text.strip()

        span = tr.find('span')  # get only from first column
        span = span.text.strip()

        data.append( (a, span) )

    tables.append(data)


for name, table in zip(names, tables):
    print('-', name)
    for a, span in table:
        print(a, span)
```